# How can I generate the url that assets:install uses for assets?

Tags: symfony, assetic

Say I reference an asset in my bundle as:

`@MyBundle\Resources\public\img\myimage.png`

And I'd like to refer to it by the path output via the assets:install console command, e.g.:
`/bundles/mybundle/img/myimage.png`

Does anyone know of a way to programmatically accomplish that? I have looked at the AssetsInstallCommand class and the algorithm used seems to be isolated. I'd rather not have to write a series of string replacement lines in an attempt to mirror the functionality, as that could be pretty brittle. Thanks for any insight!

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Could you maybe give a code example of the desired workflow?

Comment: I was trying to use some images in an email template, and didn't want to use assetic since the urls could change during a code deploy. Being that email can languish in an inbox for untold periods, expired assetic asset urls would be a bad thing. So, I wanted to use the same type of syntax to reference images in the webroot as put out by assets:install. I decided to simply put the images in a subfolder in /web, change the templates, and call it a day.

Comment: you might want to be careful with adding things manually to /web, unless your prepared to baby that directory.  I purposely dont ever use it, its only the compiled output, therefore i never have to monitor it.

Comment: I use it sparingly, for sure. In this case, I think this is the best way to go... far as I can tell. Thanks for the thoughts, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marking this as answered, as it doesn't appear possible. Any attempt to recreate the output of assets:install would require duplication of the code in that console command (/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/AssetsInstallCommand.php). My alternative solution was to simply create a new folder in /web and add my static assets there for direct reference, circumventing assetic and symfony's asset handling.